# Better parallelization of jenkins build nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, hudson, parallel-builds

I have a Jenkins jobs that runs as so (very simplified but the structure is there):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
node('my_label'){
  timestamps{
    build()
    postBuild()
  }
}

def build(){
  parallel{
    flavorABuild: {
      if(condtionA){
        node(my_label){
          stage("build flavor a"){
            sh buildcommand
          }
        }
      }
    }
    flavorBBuild: {
      if(condtionB){
        node(my_label){
          stage("build flavor B"){
            sh buildcommand
          }
        }
      }
    }
    flavorCBuild: {
      if(condtionC){
        node(my_label){
          stage("build flavor C"){
            sh buildcommand
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for my purposes as far as functionality goes, but when any of those conditions (build parameter check boxes) are not checked for building a specific flavor, that build still shows up in my BlueOcean view as a parallel build step just with no actions in it (automatically succeeded).

Is there a better/cleaner builtin way to generate conditional parallel builds? All suggestions welcome, however I am trying to avoid adding more plugins.

Comment: What do you want to do when the condition is false? Mark it as "Skipped"? Or not run it at all?

Comment: @ycr Just not run at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply omit adding the stages to the parallel execution map.  Refer to the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
node('my_label'){
  timestamps{
    parallel getParallelStages() 
  }
}

def getParallelStages() {
   def stageMap = [:]
   if(ConditionA) {
      stageMap['flavorABuild'] = { node(my_label){
        stage("build flavor a"){
          sh buildcommand
          }
        }
      }
   }

   if(ConditionB) {
      stageMap['flavorBBuild'] = { node(my_label){
        stage("build flavor B"){
          sh buildcommand
          }
        }
      }
   }
return stageMap
}
```